# Mysql select random from two tables where one column must contain two specific values

Tags: mysql

I got two tables **users** and **transactions**

I'm trying to get a random user, level = 1 in the **users** table and has both a transaction type = A and type = B on the **transactions** table.

I don't know how to select a user that has to have 2 different types of transactions.

Table `users`

```
id_user / name / level
564 - Bill - 1
565 - Joe - 1
566 - Mike - 2
```

Table `transactions`

```
id_tran  / user_id  / amount / type
85478 - 362 - 100,00  -  A
85479 - 566 - 800,00  -  D
85480 - 565 - 300,00  -  B
85481 - 405 - 800,00  -  D
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM users, transactions
WHERE user.level = "1" 
AND transactions.type = 'A' 
AND transactions.type = 'B' 
AND user.id_user = transactions.user_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE user.level = '1' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transaction WHERE transactions.type = 'A' AND transaction.user_id=user.id_user) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transaction WHERE transactions.type = 'B' AND transaction.user_id=user.id_user) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked great.